# Cannot launch the game via Wineskin

Tags: steam, macos, star-wars-kotor-2

I am trying to play KOTOR 2 on my Mac and I have everything set up - my steam is wineskinned, I have wrappers and KOTOR 2 is installed. But, whenever I go to click play game nothing happens. I click it again and it says "preparing to launch" and then I get "error app already running." It says I have played six minutes in the game but I haven't even gotten it to launch.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the game *is* running, but not properly. What does the [Activity Monitor](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41125/where-can-i-find-the-task-manager-in-mac-os-x-lion) say?

Comment: Its not appearing in the activity monitor. My wineskin steam is but not KOTOR 2.

Comment: Could this be the same issue that plagues most modern machines running Windows? Eventually graphics drivers have gotten too advanced for KOTOR 2, and it just won't launch, regardless of platform.

Comment: Also, AFAIK, KOTOR had some serious issues with Intel Graphic chips. If your Mac is using one of those, that can be another possible cause.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use Wineskin for KOTOR 2 anymore, it is supported on MacOS natively since [this update](https://steamcommunity.com/app/208580/discussions/0/541906348058768450/):

> ... proud to announce STAR WARS™ Knights of the Old Republic™ II - The Sith Lords™ is now available on Mac and Linux, along with a massive update to all 3 platforms.